# Difference: [cgi] vs. [special-effects] vs. [effects]?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference between [cgi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgi) (currently aliased to [production](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production)), [special-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-effects) and [effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects)?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @ChristianRau that it is odd to have cgi as a synonym of production (along with animals? and budget).

I've not really thought about this much but apparently Special Effects are carried out on-set and Visual Effects are in post production.  This is taken from the following article:

[What's the difference between Special Effects and Visual Effects](http://filmescape.com/2011/01/10/whats-the-difference-between-special-effects-visual-effects/)

If we are to believe this distinction, CGI would relate to Visual Effects, not Special Effects.

One proposal would be to create [visual-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-effects) and have [cgi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgi) as a synonym of it. This is not ideal IMHO.

My preferred solution would be to simplify things into an [effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects) tag and have [cgi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgi) [visual-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-effects) and [special-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-effects) all synonyms of that. Sometimes it is hard for a viewer to distinguish how an effect was done.

I would propose to leave [sound-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-effects) isolated from this.

Comment: The last option seems the most reasonable, given that I didn't know about the differentiation between *visual* and *special* effects at all (and am maybe not the only one) and the fact that the process is not always as easily separable for a complete effect.

Comment: @ChristianRau - I didn't know either, it was this question that made me discover that distinction.  I think you are correct.

Comment: We also have a [sound-effects] tag which might make things a tad confusing.

Comment: @coleopterist - yes, that does confuse things a little, but most people think visual when 'effects' are mentioned don't they?  What do you think?

Comment: IMO, the difference between visual effects and special effects is a thin one. It'll be clearer to use _one_ of them and mark the other and _cgi_ as synonyms. Just _effects_ might be a little ambiguous due to the presence of _sound-effects_. Then again, as long as we have synonyms that cover all options along with appropriate descriptions, it should be fine.

Comment: @coleopterist - I agree its a thin one, to myself as purely an enjoyer of movies, and I agree that to have effects and sound-effects is a rather imperfect solution.  What stops me agreeing fully with you is that there is a generally accepted definition in the movie industry that distinguishes between the two.  Your solution however is no more bad than mine.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say `cgi` is a special case of `special-effects` (and should thus be a synonym for that one) and `special-effects` and `effects` should be synonyms of each other (or one a synonym of the other one, you know what I mean).

Though, I don't think they should in turn be synonyms of `production`, as the latter is extremely broad but `special-effects` (or maybe `effects`) is in itself rich enough to be its own tag. I think `special-effects` is rather orthogonal to both `production` (for questions focusing more on the "bureaucratic" angle) and `film-techniques` (for the *"how's that done?"*-type of questions) and is best used *together* with those (or other tags, if any).

Comment: Agreed, to have cgi as a synonym of production seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pity we don't have hierarchical tags. To me [effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects) is the most general term encompassing many other, more specific terms. [special-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-effects) is is still broad but probably close enough to [visual-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-effects) to be a synonym. [cgi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgi) is much a more specific subset of [visual-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-effects) because it implies the effects were achieved via computer and there are many other ways to achieve some of those effects (and those ways dominated before computation was cheap).

The danger of making them all synonyms is that this sort of distinction becomes impossible to make. So if I asked what mix of visual effects were used in Gravity, i could only use one tag whereas, in the real world I might want to distinguish between the techniques used to achieve the illusion of weightlessness (possibly tagged [effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects), as it was done on set with equipment and wires), the reflected images in the astronauts visors (done with high resolution projectors onset with live images and possibly taggable  [visual-effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-effects)) and the  general background images (added post-production with CGI, and taggable [cgi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgi)).

Since we don't have hierarchies, we shouldn't rush to make tags synonyms unless there is very little distinction among them. better to recognise the utility of having some general terms and some other terms allowing specific subsets of the general terms.